# Framework7: Disable caching?

Tags: html-framework-7

I can't get caching to disable - either at an app- or page-level - in Framework7.

What I've tried:

- setting `{cache: false}` in the constructor params
- setting `{cacheIgnore: ['some_page.html']}` in the constructor params
- setting the `data-ignore-cache` attribute in the link to a page
- setting the `data-reload` attribute in a loaded page's page definition

...but I still get cached pages.

If I check the console, pages are ALWAYS loaded without an anti-cache query string, so it looks like none of these approaches are having any effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: i dont know whether you have tried this `cacheDuration: 0`

Comment: Yeah I tried all these params. I'm currently in the source code and the problem seems to be that `$.ajaxSetup()`, which is responsible for merging the user-set options with the defaults, is never called.

Comment: Are you using `template7Pages` ? If yes, it force cache to be true ([github issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues/984)

Comment: No, I'm not using template7.

Comment: the page may be alredy loaded before u set the value, try cache clean manually and reload

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define a variable *timestamp* and set it with *Date.now()* and give it to route path parameter with *?timestamp* on every route path ending.

So in this case framework7 must load every html file on every browser reload again.

after your development and design is finished you can comment it out. This scenario you can use for every framework you use. it is not framework7 specific.

**for examle:**

```
var timestamp   = Date.now();

routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './index.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/about/',
    url: './pages/about.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/form/',
    url: './pages/form.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/page-loader-template7/:user/:userId/:posts/:postId/',
    templateUrl: './pages/page-loader-template7.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/page-loader-component/:user/:userId/:posts/:postId/',
    componentUrl: './pages/page-loader-component.html?'+timestamp
  }]
```

Comment: I realise I can use the random query string approach you describe. But it's inelegant and clunky; I shouldn't have to do append this to each and every URI. There should be something in the Framework to force/disable caching. Thanks anyway.